# How to specify compatibility with iPhone only - not iPad or iPod?

Tags: iphone, ios, itunes

I just now got someone with an iPad buying my app (after 1 year the first case) who does not have an iPhone.

The bad thing is that my app communicates via SMS or phone calls, so it only works on iPhone.

I even specifically set that in the "Targeted Device family" - but I guess that doesn't matter to iTunes - is says in the requirements within iTunes still iPhone, iPad or iPod.

Is there anything similar to Android's filter logic on iTunes that avoids users to get the App on iPad?

While certainly I have this clearly written in the description - I rather like to avoid having to explain this to users who bought the app and don't have an iPhone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, but you can specify which capabilities the device needs to have using the [`UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html) dictionary.

Comment: The key to require an iPhone is `telephony`. Since the question mentions SMS, the `sms` key might be an option as well.

Comment: Thanks - Does this then "filter out" the App in iTunes or what implications does this have that would help to avoid downloading this on iPad?

Comment: yes. it wont work on ipad (except if the bring ipad 4 with a telephone)

Comment: I know it does not "work" on iPad - but I need to make sure that someone does not BUY the app on iPad if he does not have an iPhone! Imagine having paid for an app that installs on your iPad but needs telephony - you will be rather angry and give bad reviews - I like to avoid this alltogether if possible.

Comment: @user387184 They won't be able to buy it through the mobile store on unsupported devices, but you they can still buy it via iTunes (although it will no longer say that it runs on iPad and iPod)

Comment: docs, line 1: "UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities (Array or Dictionary - iOS) lets iTunes and the App Store know which device-related features an app requires in order to run. iTunes and the mobile App Store use this list to prevent customers from installing apps on a device that does not support the listed capabilities"

Comment: ...yes and the docs also say: "Include this key if your app requires (or specifically prohibits) the presence of the Messages app" - so I include it if the app requires OR prohibits it? Strange. So I just added the text "telephony" and "sms" as item0 and item1, also I find it rather weird, that one can just type text and it is not an enumerated value - mistyped values are ignored I guess and don't cause errors - they are not checked it seems. Anyway, hope it will work for sure and not hide the app since I do not understand why anyone would include it if the App explicitly prohibits sms?

Comment: @user387184 They are keys for a dictionary entires with boolean types. `YES` means that it's required, `NO` means it's prohibited.

Comment: @JustSid , Actually when I add "Required device capabilities" as a new row it is added as an array type with strings as elements. On the left it says item0 on the right I have to type the value. One cannot change the type of the values. What is wrong?

Comment: I tried - one cannot edit item0, one can only edit it's string value. "Required device capabilities" is an array, not a dictionary

Comment: downvoter: please leave comment so one knows why the downvote

Answer (score 1):

You can add a key `telephony` in the plist under `UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities`

For more details refer:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html

Answer (score 0):

Besides Djan suggestion, you can do one more thing just at your didFinishLaunching check the device family via UIDevice, and if it's not belong to iPhone just redirect to some other page with an error message or whatever you intend.

Comment: yes.. if you really require a model check..... the capabilities show in appstore. [nonetheless, this answer is valid and sometimes useful. e.g. I remember implementing an app where I needed to make performance compromises for older devices]

Comment: This is not allowed as per the review guidelines. `Apps that arbitrarily restrict which users may use the App, such as by location or carrier, may be rejected` and `Apps that do not perform as advertised by the developer will be rejected`

Comment: Thanks Mr. JustSid for mentioning this important point but as per Rahul quote, since this app uses CTelephony api as well as in the description at iTune as he already specified how this app behave(as much I think so), the AppStore has no objection for using this tact as we are selling what we are elaborating... and, also the same I've used in one of my app which is already present in the AppStore.